# Interval range insert with split into unique ranges

Tags: javascript, algorithm, language-agnostic, pseudocode

Looking for algorithm ideas how to insert into interval range value so it won't overlap existing intervals.

Interval range is sorted **smallest to larger** [[0, 1], [3, 5]].

Now inserting interval range [0, 7] to [[0, 1], [3, 5]] -> [[0, 1], [1, 3], [3, 5], [5, 7]] -> generated two new ranges other remain same.

Here is another example, inserting range [-3, 5] to [[0, 1], [6,7]] -> [[-3, 0], [0, 1], [1, 5], [6, 7]]

All programming languages(especially JavaScript) are welcomed also pseudocode implementations.

Comment: We can't pick a language for you.

Comment: I added JavaScript tag but any C like(php, java, c#, python) also pseudocode is welcomed.

Comment: You want "better" algorithms but haven't posted your own...

Comment: This would be better off in codereview or, possibly, codegolf.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Checking interval overlap is covered quite well on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.

Comment: Why does language matter? The "algorithm" tag without a specific language pretty clearly indicates that the OP wants an algorithm: a roadmap for solving the problem. He didn't ask for a specific implementation.

Comment: Why, in your first example, would you end up with five different ranges? Why not have it create a single range, `[0-7]`?

Comment: @JimMischel valid question, in the actual code there is a differentiation between old interval ranges and new ranges after applying certain operation those ranges would be merged together. I wanted to split the question into smaller chunk so the merging part is left out.

Comment: Just that it probably is easier to merge the new interval in directly - instead of having to split explicitly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the actual code there is a differentiation between old interval ranges and new ranges after applying certain operation those ranges would be merged together. I wanted to split the question into smaller chunk so the merging part is left out.

Solely: It is easier to merge in the new interval directly, instead of artificially splitting it up. So this is what I propose below (C++):

```
using DataType = /* whatever appropriate; double, int, unsigned int, ...*/;
using Interval = std::pair<DataType, DataType>;
std::vector<Interval> intervals;

void insert(Interval x)
{
    if(intervals.empty() || x.second < intervals.front().first)
    {
        intervals.insert(intervals.begin(), x); // (1)
    }
    else if(x.first > intervals.back().second)
    {
        intervals.push_back(x); // (2)
    }
    else
    {
        auto b = intervals.begin();
        while(b->second < x.first)
        {
            std::advance(b, 1);
        }
        // cannot be END iterator, otherwise would have been caught by (2)
        if(x.second < b->first)
        {
            // this is a new interval in between std::prev(b) and (b)
            intervals.insert(b, x);
        }
        else
        {
            // b is overlapping with x!
            if(b->first > x.first)
            {
                b->first = x.first;
            }

            auto e = std::next(b);
            while(e != intervals.end() && e->first <= x.second)
            {
                std::advance(e, 1);
            }
            // e is the first interval NOT overlapping with x!
            auto l = std::prev(e);
            b->second = std::max(x.second, l->second);
            // drop all subsequent intervals now contained in b (possibly none)
            intervals.erase(std::next(b), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Algorithm only, spared the design efforts of packing into class, having convenience function accepting begin/end markers (instead of interval), ...

If the data type you intend to use does not provide a back accessor (C++: e. g. `std::forward_list`): No problem, just drop the second `if` (containing `(2)`); then, however, `b` *can* be the end iterator, so you'd have to test for and if the test succeeds, you can insert at end. You'd most likely not have an 'insert before' then, so you'd need to track b's and later e's predecessors separately, too...